# ionic2 ion-list with a button both having (click) event

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

What I am trying to achieve is when I click on the download button it should do somthing else and when clicking on the item it should open a new window

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let reading_material of reading_materials" (click)="gotoReadingMaterial(reading_material)">
        {{reading_material.title}}
        <ion-icon item-right name="download" (click)="downloadMaterial(reading_material)"></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

But when I click on the download button, both the events gets hit.
Is there a way i can suppress the item event when i click on the download button ??

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can solve this issue by using `event.stopPropagation();`.

Please take a look at [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YsNJjm8PNKlSrlOQogmD?p=preview).

like you can see there, I also send the `$event` object to both methods

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="open($event, item)">
        {{ item }}
        <ion-icon (click)="download($event, item)" item-right name="download"></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

And then I use that information to stop the propagation of the event, so only the download method will be executed when clicking the download icon

```
  public open(event, item) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert('Open ' + item);
  }

  public download(event, item) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert('Download ' + item);
  }
```

Comment: Your plunker seems empty ?

Comment: @MichaëlPolla yeah, the plunker was using a older version of Ionic. I'll create another one and update the answer asap. Anyway, the most relevant parts of the code are what you can see in the answer :)

Comment: @MichaëlPolla the plunker has been updated... Sorry for the delay :)