# Ionic 3 - list view with buttons referencing the clicked item

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a simple list with buttons layout:

```
  <ion-list inset *ngFor="let audio of event.audios; let i = index">
      <ion-item>

        <div class="item-text-center item-text-wrap">  {{audio.fileName}} </div>

        <ion-buttons end>
          <button  end ion-button icon-only color="primary" (click)="playAudio(audio)">
            <ion-icon name="{{playButtonIcon}}"></ion-icon>
          </button>
          <button  end ion-button icon-only color="primary" (click)="deleteAudio(audio)">
            <ion-icon name="close"></ion-icon>
          </button>
        </ion-buttons>

      </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Note that there is a variable playButtonIcon that changes each time a button in the list is clicked.

**Problem**: Each time I click an item in the list *every* item in the list changes it's icon. That does not make sense. Only the button in the clicked item should change.

**Question**: How can I achieve to change the button icon of the clicked item ? My idea until now was to have an extra array containing for each item in the list the variable `playButtonIcon` to change from stop to play. But that does not seem like the way to go. Is there an official pattern for that case?

**Note**: I know that I can get the item clicked. An example can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847181/ionic2-ion-list-with-a-button-both-having-click-event).  But in my data model there is no field `playButtonIcon` because it is just a technical thing and thus I need another way to access the button of the clicked item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you try something like this

> view.html

```
     <button  end ion-button icon-only color="primary" (click)="playAudio(audio)">
  <ion-icon name="{{playButtonIcon}}" *ngIf="typeOf audio.isPlaying == 'undefined'">{{Playbuttonicon}}</ion-icon>
  <ion-icon name="{{pauseButtonIcon}}" *ngIf="typeOf audio.isPlaying != 'undefined'">{{PauseButtonIcon}}</ion-icon>
</button>
```

> component.ts

```
playAudio(audio){
//get the index of the current audio in the array 
 let idx = this.audios.indexOf(audio);
//make a new property called isPlaying and assign a boolean true
this.audios[idx]["isPlaying"] = true; 
}
```

Or Else re loop the array and add an extra property called icon and on click change the icon.