# event.prevent default is not working in Ionic 3.

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to learn ionic 3 by making a demo application. My application is very simple. I am adding some text. showing this text by using ion-lists. After that, if we tap on this list, details page will come. Till now everything is going properly. But for making more complex, I am using two buttons named edit and delete on this lists. But now the main problem what I am facing that is, always details function is calling. I can't do anything with this two buttons(edit and delete). How may I resolve this issue ?

I am sending my code here.

## Html

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item>
            <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Add Tasks" [(ngModel)] = 'addtasks'></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <button ion-button round (click)='addTasks(addtasks)'>Add Tasks</button>


<ion-list >
    <div ion-item *ngFor="let task of taskLists" (click)="taskSelected(task)">
        {{ task.tasksname }}
        <button ion-button (click)="delete(task)">Delete</button>
        <button ion-button (click)="edit(task)">Edit</button>
    </div>
</ion-list>
```

## Component

```
   taskSelected(task) {
    console.log("Tasks");
 }
 delete(task, event) {
     console.log('task    ..');
 }
```

How I can use all 3 buttons ?

Comment: Div will overlap button so click event in DIV will only be triggered not the click event in buttons. you can call this function by creating another span tag over task name.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847181/ionic2-ion-list-with-a-button-both-having-click-event