# How to make buttons in a card clickable in Ionic 2

Tags: html, angular, ionic2

I have made a card in an ionic 2 as shown below. When the card is clicked, it leads to another page.

```html
<ion-content padding class="item item-text-wrap">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor='let topic of topicList' text-wrap (click)="redirect(topic)">
        <ion-thumbnail id="storyThumbnail">
          <img src="{{ topic.picDirectory }}">
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <div id="caption">
          <h2><strong>{{ topic.headline }}</strong></h2>
          <p id="artDate">{{ topic.date }}</p>
          <ion-icon name="bookmark" id="icon"></ion-icon>
          <!--<button id="viewButton" ion-button clear item-end  (click)="postItem(topic)">View</button>-->
          <ion-icon name="logo-facebook" id="icon"></ion-icon>
        </div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

When I add a button as indicated (commented), I cannot click the button. When I click the button it reacts as though I am clicking the whole card, it calls redirect() instead of postItem(). The button will use data from the topic so I cannot put it outside of the ion-item since it contains the ngFor but when I put it inside the ion-item, I cannot click it.

It appears the button is behind the ion-item and therefore is unaccessable by clicking. Is there a way in which I can make it clickable while it's inside the item?

Comment: Please take a look at **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39847181/ionic2-ion-list-with-a-button-both-having-click-event/39849566#39849566)**, I think you can do the same on your code to fix that issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have added **(click)="redirect(topic)"** at **ion-item** level which represent the whole card, hence when you click on the button it actually clicking on the whole card.

To resolve this - You need to remove **(click)** event call from ion-item and un-comment your button code, it should work.

let me know.